# Check if IP is in network on Python3

Tags: python

I am trying to run a routine on two lists, sourced from MySQL queries - one contains CIDR networks and the other contains IP addresses. I am trying to compare entries in the IP list to see whether they are in the networks described by the CIDR list, and act on those that are not.

I am trying to use the `netaddr` module but this doesn't appear to be implemented on Python3 yet?

I have also tried to use `ipaddress` but I can't seem to get them to compare correctly. Using ipaddress I have the following code:

```
networks = (('1.1.6.0/20',), ('2.8.2.0/19',), ('7.2.2.0/19',), ('2.2.0.0/19',))

ips = ((8888, 'customer', b'2.8.4.64', '8888*200'),(8888, 'customer', b'1.1.6.3', '8888*201'), (8888, 'customer', b'122.223.159.3', '8888*202'))

straglers = list()

for ip in ips:
    exclude = 0
    for network in networks:
        subnet = ip_network(network[0])
        if ip_address(ip[2]) in subnet:
            exclude = 1
    if exclude == 0:
        straglers.append([ip[3],ip[2],ip[1]]) # extension, customer_ip, company
```

As things stand the code gives a value error as follows: `ValueError: b'82.148.47.64' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address`

I have tried converting `ip[2]` to an utf-8 string but this makes no difference.

Comment: FWIW, I've used [IPy](https://pypi.org/project/IPy/) in the past and been most pleased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing as a list is actually a tuple.

First, when I ran your code I did not receive the error you are getting

> ValueError: b'82.148.47.64' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

Instead I received the following

> raise ValueError('%s has host bits set' % self)
>   ValueError: 1.1.6.0/20 has host bits set

Is this the error your are actually receiving? If so, this is how to properly correct it.

Referenced from ipaddress module [Defining Networks](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html#defining-networks):

> By default, attempting to create a network object with host bits set will result in ValueError being raised. To request that the additional bits instead be coerced to zero, the flag strict=False can be passed to the constructor:

This is because the host bits are set and will need to be coerced to zero, as the documentation states above. Pass the following flag **strict=False** to the constructor.

For example.

```
subnet = ip_network(network[0], strict=False)
```

Also, in your ips contained in your tuple need only to be formatted to a string.

For example.

```
ips = ((8888, 'customer', '2.8.4.64', '8888*200')
```

OR the following will be presented to you.

> 'ValueError: **b'2.8.4.64'** does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address'

The full working code.

```
from ipaddress import ip_network, ip_address
networks = (('1.1.6.0/20',), ('2.8.2.0/19',), ('7.2.2.0/19',), ('2.2.0.0/19',))

ips = ((8888, 'customer', b'2.8.4.64', '8888*200'),(8888, 'customer', b'1.1.6.3', '8888*201'), (8888, 'customer', b'122.223.159.3', '8888*202'))

straglers = list()

for ip in ips:
    exclude = 0
    for network in networks:
        subnet = ip_network(network[0], strict=False)  
        print(ip_address(ip[2].decode('utf-8')))
        print(subnet)
        if ip_address(ip[2].decode('utf-8')) in subnet:
            exclude = 1
    if exclude == 0:
        straglers.append([ip[3],ip[2],ip[1]]) # extension, customer_ip, company
print(straglers)
```

Comment: Thanks - you were right about the tuple, my bad :-/  How can I format the IPs to a string? They come from a DB, this is how the query returns them.

Comment: The `b'` prefix says that however you are reading those from the database is getting the raw bytes rather than the string which `ipaddress` expects. You can call `.decode()` on them using the appropriate encoding – presumably UTF-8 or ASCII. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode.

Comment: I have updated the working example above using using the conversion that Chris Adams suggested. See line "if ip_address(ip[2].decode('utf-8')) in subnet:". I tried it and it seems to work with ips as b'2.8.4.64'.